# Laravel how to delete default blades

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have a android app with laravel backend. I don't have a website as of now.

Since browser access is not required, can I delete the blades in resource views folder without affecting core/android functionality? I am especially worried about login/register blades and the default welcome blade which links to login/register. Also, is there any other file that I can/should delete along with these blades?

I am assuming after deleting these files, I need to run `composer update` and everything will be fine?

Comment: If you remove the blade file then you will face an error on that page, which is ok if debug mode is off.

Comment: Oh, how do I fix/remove that error? Any idea?

Comment: The error occurs because Laravel can not load the blade file. You can just remove everything from that blade file and leave it empty. or you can remove the route.

Comment: Thank you. I made them blank files. Hope that should be okay (from a security standpoint).

Comment: The login page and registration pages still will be accessible. You need to delete those routes. I think its best to find someone to do it for you.

Comment: Yes, routes are deleted and both files made blank.Thanks.

Comment: composer should have nothing to do with frontend templates